# Why am I not receiving attachment with Jenkins Email-ext plug in?

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, email-ext

I have a job generating report My_Report.html in the root of workspace. I can see it when visually inspecting job's workspace (Jenkins/job/myjob/ws/). I'm using email-ext plug in to generate an email. I have the following under Attachments configuration:

> **/My_Report.html

I do get an email, however report is not attached. 
Thank you in advance for any suggestions.